# Terminating a @Scheduled Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I'm struggling with the following problem. I have a single Spring Batch Job which is executed every 10 minutes via a `@Scheduled` method. If a job execution fails, I need to terminate the schedule. I know how to do this either by
 a) calling `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor::postProcessBeforeDestruction()` 
 or
 b) making a custom `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, storing `ScheduledFutures` and then cancel()ing them,

but in both cases the problem is the same : tons of Spring Batch `TransactionSystemExceptions` because it can no longer commit metadata. And despite not having any more `@Scheduled` tasks to run, the application doesn't terminate...

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Is you JVM running **only** the batch job in a scheduled way? Is stopping the Spring Application context and gracefully shutting down the JVM after the job failure an option for you?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine That sounds perfect but how can I achieve this ?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine For instance, if I do an SpringApplication.exit() from within a JobListener, I still get a number of Exceptions. An InterruptedException from the datasource as well as a few CannotCreateTransactionExceptions presumably due to SpringBatch trying to write metadata to the db... same deal if using ConfigurableApplicationContext.close()

Comment: Best I've managed so far is to call softEvictConnections() on HikariPoolMXBean until there are no more active connections and then to perform StringApplication.exit() ... seems hacky though...

Comment: ok thanks for the details. See my answer on how to do it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If guess (from the tags) you are using Spring Boot. So in that case, please note that boot emits an `ApplicationEvent` of type `JobExecutionEvent` with the `JobExecution` as payload. So you can create a bean that implements `ApplicationListener<JobExecutionEvent>` and gracefully shutdown the application context if the job fails.

Hope this helps.